# R: Use VAR model to predict response to change in values of certain variables

Tags: r, model, statistics, regression

I've fitted a VECM model in R, and converted in to a VAR representation. I would like to use this model to predict the future value of a response variable based on different scenarios for the explanatory variables.

Here is the code for the model:

```
library(urca)
library(vars)

input <-read.csv("data.csv")
ts <- ts(input[16:52,],c(2000,1),frequency=4)
dat1 <- cbind(ts[,"dx"], ts[,"u"], ts[,"cci"],ts[,"bci"],ts[,"cpi"],ts[,"gdp"])

args('ca.jo')
vecm <- ca.jo(dat1, type = 'trace', K = 2, season = NULL,spec="longrun",dumvar=NULL)
vecm.var <- vec2var(vecm,r=2)
```

Now what I would like do is to predict "dx" into the future by varying the others. I am not sure if something like "predict dx if u=30,cpi=15,bci=50,gdp=..." in the next period would work. So what I have in mind is something along the lines of: increase "u" by 15% in the next period (which would obviously impact on all the other variables as well, including "dx") and predict the impact into the future.

Also, I am not sure if the "vec2var" step is necessary, so please ignore it if you think it is redundant.

Thanks
Karl

Comment: This question has more to do with econometrics than with programming.  There is more of a critical mass on the r-sig-finance mailing list for this subject, so you might try posting it there.

Answer (score 2):

This subject is covered very nicely in Chapters 4 and 8 of Bernhard Pfaff's book, "[Analysis of Integrated and Cointegrated Time Series with R](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387759662)", for which the **vars** and **urca** packages were written.

The vec2var step is necessary if you want to use the predict functionality that's available.

A more complete answer [was provided on the R-Sig-Finance list](http://old.nabble.com/R:-Use-VAR-model-to-predict-response-to-change-in-values-of-certain-variables-td26477723.html).  See also [this related thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg04938.html).

Comment: I am actually using the book that you refer to, but it doesn't quite spell out how I could do what I am trying to do, and neither do the answers above. The answer to my question on R-Sig-Finance is close, but I can't use it because it extracts the lm from an object "varest", whereas I don't see how that van be done with a "vec2var" object.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go - ??forecast gave vars::predict, Predict method for objects of class varest and vec2var as an answer, which looks precisely as you want it. Increasing u looks like impulse response analysis, so look it up!